# Match Columns Between 2 Files and Print

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files, `fileA` and `fileB` as shown below:

`fileA`:

```
chrM    150     .       T       C       7807.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=247;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=4.7038;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=51.13;MQ0=0;QD=31.61;VQSLOD=3.92;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL       1/1:0,247:247:99:7836,727,0
chrM    195     .       C       T       5638.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=176;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=2.5193;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.23;MQ0=0;QD=32.04;VQSLOD=3.62;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL       1/1:0,176:176:99:5667,517,0
chrM    199     rs72619362      T       C       5058.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=169;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.7887;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.55;MQ0=0;QD=29.93;VQSLOD=4.68;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)       GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,169:169:99:5087,472,0
chrM    204     rs3135032       T       C       4110.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=168;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.77;MQ0=0;QD=24.47;VQSLOD=2.90;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)       GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,168:168:99:4139,435,0
```

`fileB`:

```
chrM    150   .       T       C       15      sfail   3       GT:DP:FT:GQ:GL          1/0:4:PASS:30:-3.27436,-0.000346498,-12.6286
chr1    10025   .       T       C       15      sfail   3       GT:DP:FT:GQ:GL          1/0:4:PASS:30:-3.27436,-0.000346498,-12.6286
```

If the first two columns of both files match, then the output should be all the columns of `fileA` and the 10 column of `fileB`.

If I had to only match the columns I could have done this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} $0 in a' fileA fileB
```

But getting the 10th column from `fileB` is bit tricky. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is just

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$0; next} ($1,$2) in a {print a[$1,$2], $10}' fileA fileB
```

Store lines from `fileA` by fields `$1` and `$2`.
For every line in `fileB` that matches a stored field print out the stored line and the tenth field from the current line.